# 6502 BASIC removing a character

Tags: string, basic

How do I delete a character in 6502 basic?  Like reverse print...
Would there be a way to channel the del key code into a program?  I have tried looking at the reference but there is nothing there for a command.

Comment: Any particular dialect?  Is this on a C64, VIC 20 or something else? https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/control_character has chr$(20) as a back space.  So PRINT "ABC"+CHR$(20) prints AB

Comment: I've been using an xpet using the VICE emulator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As OldBoyCoder suggests, it can be done - but the character depends on the platform.

```
10 PRINT "AB";
20 PRINT "C"
```

Output on [Commodore PET](http://www.skibo.net/6502/pet2001/) or Apple II:

```
ABC
```

For Commodore PET add:

```
15 PRINT CHR$(20);
```

Output:

```
AC
```

On the Apple II you'd need to use 8 instead of 20 because the I/O firmware is different.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the string manipulation commands, such as `LEFT$`, `RIGHT$` and `MID$`, here's an untested example from memory (for the Commodore PET and other Commodore 8-bit machines, probably also works on other variants of BASIC):

```
 0 A$="ABC"
 1 PRINT LEFT$(A$,2): REM PRINTS AB
 2 PRINT RIGHT$(A$,2): REM PRINTS BC
 3 PRINT MID$(A$,2,1): REM PRINTS B
```

Otherwise, you can over-write characters as long as you know where they are located on the screen.

```
 0 D$=CHR$(17): REM CURSOR DOWN
 1 U$=CHR$(145): REM CURSOR UP
 2 R$=CHR$(29): REM CURSOR RIGHT
 3 L$=CHR$(157): REM CURSOR LEFT
 4 PRINT "ABC";L$;" "
```

I'm using CHR$ codes here for clarity. If you open a string with a double-quote, you can press the UP/DOWN and LEFT/RIGHT keys which will show inversed characters. Printing these inversed characters will do the same as moving the cursor around with the cursor keys.